# custom message for dependency required field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 fields - type(hw/sw),hardware type(dropdown) and asset_request.'Type' field is dropdown hardware(1) and software(2).'hardware type' has phone(1),camera(2),others(3)

If I chosen hardware(1),hardware type field is mandary and asset_request field is not mandatory.

If I chosen software(0) only asset_request field is mandatory.

If I chosen type=hardware(1) and hardware type=others(3) asset_request field is mandatory. so my validation is like

```
$this->validate($request,[
                'hardware_type' => 'required_without:asset_request',
                'asset_request' => 'required_without:hardware_type|required_if:hardware_type,==,3',

            ],$messages);
```

if I filled type and left hardware type now display the message.I want to display only one error message.Is it possible to do  foe dependency fields.

```
The hardware type field is required when asset request is not present.
The asset request field is required when hardware type is not present.
```

Comment: It it expected to work like that. You are free to output only the first error in your view.

Comment: how to show only the first error

Comment: this depends on how you are printing the errors to the user. Please share blade code. Sth. like `{{ $errors->first() }}`